# How did Britain rule Sri Lanka?

Tags: british-empire, colonization, everyday-life

How did Britain rule Sri Lanka. Apart from the Great Rebellion, in which the British Empire brutally repressed the Kandy kingdom, there isn't a lot of info on how life was really like under foreign rule, especially during the early half of the 20th century. So what was it really like to be Ceylonese in the pre-war? How did British rule compare with life prior to the Empire?

Comment: This question seems to contain more than a hint of hyperbole, especially in the first sentence. What evidence do you have to support the genocide tag?

Comment: Considering you've already decided it was genocide, I don't know what kind of answers you expect for this "question".

Comment: I'd recommend that you (1) edit the question to some semblance of scholarly detachment and (2) refine what you want in the answer. "how bad was..." is likely to invite opinion answers.   What is it you're really looking for.

Comment: I think the question might be closed on the grounds that a reasonable person would find accusations of genocide to be rude or offensive. (unless supported by evidence).

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: And that any knowledge of history would find a notable lack of evidence.

Comment: @SteveBird - The Great Rebellion was a delightful affair. The British murdered every adult male in Uva and systematically dismantled their irrigation systems to impoverish, starve and displace the rest. Lots of evidence from this one colonial war alone.

Comment: I understand the question is a platform to push indignation at British colonialism, but a serious answer to this question would have to deal with the fact that life under British rule changed drastically during the century+ time. British administrative policy markedly changed before and after 1832, for instance. Thus, even without the hyperbole and the nvitation to condemn, imo the question remains rather broad.

Comment: @Semaphore - No, it's pretty much one answer; violent transformation from a culture based on spice cultivation and trade to a vast plantation system reliant on enormous amounts of imported labor. The details in how they did this are many and horrible, but this is what it boils down to. Answerable, and nominated for re-opening.

Comment: @RISwampYankee Really, plantations were the basis of British rule of Ceylon in the first half of the 20th century? What about the early 1800s, when Ceylon was a military outpost? It's all the same?

Comment: I mean, even with my limited understanding here, I'd imagine that the early focus on road building using compulsory labour makes for quite a different view of "how life was really like", vs when the obligation was formally renounced and the British administration moved towards plantations with a failed vision of wage labour force.

Comment: @Semaphore - Yup. It began with the co-option of the cinnamon trade in particular, and moved to the vast cash-crop plantations that were still going strong in the early 20th (rubber and tea). You can trip over the details in piece but they're still parts of the larger whole. The British Empire used violence, starvation and forced labor to coerce the island to produce revenue and resources for itself at the expense of the Sri Lankans. Toss in a few examples from the beginning, middle and end, and citations, and we're done.

Comment: @RI Swamp Yankee: And the pre-colonial rulers didn't use "violence, starvation and forced labor" to produce revenues for themselves at the expense of the majority?  That's what government IS.

Answer (score 1):

Annihilated?

British administration was beneficial for the Indian economy. After the British left, the Indian economy declined very significantly. In 1900, India was ranked the #36 country in the world by GDP per capita. Today, it is ranked #135, right below Nigeria.

To put that in perspective: if India were #36 today, it would be comparable to Israel (#35) and Spain (#33).

Comment: British Raj also did the highly important job of unifying the sub-continent into a nation. Pre-Raj it was a mix of largely feudal princely states. Health outcomes also improved substantially under the raj, despite the few famines which have been skewed and politicized.

Comment: Once every few decades, hundreds of thousands and sometimes millions would die of famine due to British mismanagement - think of the various Irish "famines" on a grander scale. Worth it for that sweet, sweet GDP! (that was taken at bayonet-point and shipped back to England.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_major_famines_in_India_during_British_rule

Comment: Not to side with the questioner, but if it was so wonderful being ruled by the British (such as yours truly), why are they not grovelling in gratitude?

Comment: @RI Swamp Yankee: To be fair, the famines (and wars, terrorizing of populations, &c) under British rule should be compared to those before and after the British.

Comment: @jamesqf - This is pretty well covered under the Bengali Famine wiki page. The British outlawed "hoarding" rice and other staples ("harding"  defined as storing it for lean years in case of famine, as had been the custom for centuries, because the British demanded a bigger cut of the harvest and its profits) and what arable land there *was* during the drought had their food crops ripped up and devoted to opium production. So, yes, let's *do* compare.

Comment: @RI Swamp Yankee: So where is the comparison to conditions before and after the British?  Was your example worse than say the 1971 Bangladesh "genocide"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1971_Bangladesh_genocide

Comment: @jamesqf YUP! Almost 11 million dead in the Bengali Famine alone, between 300k and 2 million dead in the Bangladesh War of Independence.

Comment: India went through famines every few decades both before and after the start of colonial rule. It's not a comparison to only criticise British policy without any attempt to draw comparisons with historical famine severity. Although I am under the impression that famines became more severe and regular under Company rule, merely pointing out that it occurred while ignoring pre-colonial history does not make for a convincing case.

Comment: @Semaphore The British made it drastically worse is the entire point, the magnitude of suffering was unheard of before the Raj got involved for the reasons pointed out above - restrictions on storing food as a buffer for famines, imposing a "free market" that made what food there was too expensive for fieldworkers and artisans, replacing food crops with opium production. Famines happen. I get it. They *don't* happen with the same frequency or massive severity before or after the British. Famines and their causes and contributing factors are pretty well studied and understood.

Comment: @RISwampYankee The point is that endlessly asserting the "British made it worse" without any attempt to demonstrate it by drawing concrete comparisons to pre-colonial famines, is not an effective argument. You've talked at length on the mechanism (you believe) by which British rule supposedly made it "drastically worse", without bothering to demonstrate that the premise is true. I do agree with some of your points, but so far this comment chain is not only off topic but also appears to be talking past each other because of that. This is not a topic of interest for me so I'll leave here.

Comment: @RI Swamp Yankee: You also can't really demonstrate, at least without some unbiased analysis (and may I say that your bias is pretty darned obvious?) that the British made the famine worse.  It might be that without the British actions the death toll would have been even higher.

Comment: @Semaphore Oh, good grief. Well let me just google that for you. Here, a well maintained wiki page with a lot of scholarly references to follow up with - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famine_in_India

Comment: @RISwampYankee I wasn't trying to debate you, I was pointing out the glaringly obvious flaw in your line of attack. It isn't me who you have to convince, but constantly falling back to Wikipedia as your only apparent source of knowledge isn't really helping your case.